# Any simple proof of that localization of a UFD is a UFD without using Kaplansky condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Using Kaplansky condition, the proof of this statement is quite easy. Before knowing this condition, I tried to prove this statement by actually showing the definition of UFD holds on $S^{-1}A$ ($A$ factorial). On the course of this proof, (actually at the point where I need to prove the uniqueness of factorization after proving the existence of it--I've proved the existence) I needed to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789979/for-a-entire-s-multiplicative-subset-if-x-s-in-s-1a-is-irreducible/790035?noredirect=1#790035) for my proof steps to actually work. But [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789979/for-a-entire-s-multiplicative-subset-if-x-s-in-s-1a-is-irreducible/790035?noredirect=1#790035) turned out false. (One of the textbooks I use actually use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789979/for-a-entire-s-multiplicative-subset-if-x-s-in-s-1a-is-irreducible/790035?noredirect=1#790035) statement without proving it so I also tired to employ it in my proof.)

So I'm quite stuck now. All my approaches I tried needed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789979/for-a-entire-s-multiplicative-subset-if-x-s-in-s-1a-is-irreducible/790035?noredirect=1#790035) at some point on the proof.

But I guess there should be an elegant proof of it, even without using the Kaplansky condition? Any suggestion or reference?

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/150848/242) for some background and conceptual hints.

Comment: I didn't know about the Kaplansky condition! This is very interesting.